# Constraint layout constraint dimension ratio not working with multiple views

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am having issue with constraint dimension ratio. Width and height of image view is not adjusting. I want to make image thumb view square depending on the ratio. I want the width and height of image thumb equal to total height of three text views given in the layout. Also current code is not loading image into image view.

[image: Image of Layout]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintAList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:id="@+id/audioThumb"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_headset"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/audioDetail"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/audioName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/audioName"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/roundImageView" />     

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/audioName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:lines="2"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="audioName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/audioTime"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/audioThumb"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/audioTime"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="audioDate"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/audioDetail"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/audioName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/audioName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/audioName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/audioDetail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="audioDuration"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/audioTime"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/audioTime"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/audioTime" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Add `android:layout_height="0dp"` to the _ImageView_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **ImageView**

- set `android:layout_height="0dp"` and
- remove `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/audioName"`